# SSRS Report runs locally but not on server ... but runs on server if I rename the report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that I have been working on for a while. It has required a large number of redeploys as I make changes in VS and examine their effects on the report on the server. The report never has any issues in VS.

All of a sudden the report will no longer load on the server - it doesnt even load parameter selection, the report link simply returns "Reporting Services Error For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors."

Here's the kicker - IF I CHANGE THE NAME OF THE REPORT IT RUNS AGAIN. Not only that but future deployments of said report continue to run ... until all of a sudden they dont and I receive the same error message again... until I rename the report again. If at any point I try to revert back to the old file name the report will no longer run.

I am deploying the report a LARGE number of times ... every time I make any edit I test it on the server. Am I perhaps overloading a log file for that report name? I have no idea what's going on.

I am working on getting remote errors enabled but I work for a very large company and have been waiting for days for a response.

Any ideas?

Comment: A couple things to check. Is your data source working on the report server? Also, Do you have any caching enabled on the server for the report? Those are my two best guesses.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the current report and re-deploying? SSRS does have an issue with parameter default values NOT updating when re-deploying.

Comment: @BrandonJohnson Caching is disabled and the data sets within the report point at shared data sources that are used by all my reports on the server, the rest of which are working. thanks though.

Comment: @HannoverFist if I delete the report and redeploy it under a different name the report works, if I re deploy under the same name it continues to show the error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it had to do with Chrome caching versions of the report. I had the server set up to run the report every time but chrome seemed to be doing it anyway. If I close and reopen all of chrome instead of simply closing the tab the report starts working again.

Not really an "answer" as to why its happening but definitely found my path forwards.

thanks to everyone for their input.